# Hide a toolbar programmatically

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I found a lot of discussion, but anyonw work fine for me.
I create a toolBar in a viewcontroller :

```
UIToolbar *toolBar =[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - 49,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 49)];

[toolBar setTranslucent:YES];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *buttonfb = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(condividiFB)];
UIBarButtonItem *buttontw = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(condividiTW)];

NSArray *toolbaritems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, buttonfb,flexibleSpace, buttontw,flexibleSpace, nil];
toolBar.items = toolbaritems;

[self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

it's OK. the toolbar appers very cute, but i want hide or move it during a scroll.
i detect the scroll and call a method with the follow solution but doen't work.
when i try to hide the toolbar, neither.
i try with a lot of solution that i toke here.
for esample :

```
[self.toolBar removeFromSuperview];
```

but nothing;
another way:

```
[_toolBar setHidden:YES];
```

neither;

try to move:

```
self.toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.toolBar.frame.origin.x, self.toolBar.frame.origin.y + 100, self.toolBar.frame.size.width, self.toolBar.frame.size.height);
```

nothing works.
I'm gettin crazy.

Comment: At the moment you never set `self.toolBar` (at least not in the code you posted).

Comment: After `[self.view addSubview:toolBar]` add `[toolBar setHidden:YES]`. Now it disappears, doesn't it?

Comment: hmmm, self.toolbar is nil, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the toolbar up with the property you defined rather than the locally scoped variable in your example.

Change this:

```
UIToolbar * toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - 49,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 49)];
```

To this:

```
self.toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - 49,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 49)];
```

Comment: The OP already has such a property (see the code where `self.toolBar` is used).

Comment: You're right. He just needs to set the property he already has.

Comment: it works, thanks so much.
In effect i create the toolbar like suggest above:

    self.toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size

thanks so much o everybody.